# multiple regression - interpreting the plots of the model

Tags: multiple-regression, residuals, interpretation

I'm doing a multiple regression analysis with up to 9403 observations without any prior hypothesis.
The AIC and BIC variable selection both generated the same ideal model. After I `plot(modelfit)`, I have difficulty interpreting them:
[image: Residual vs Fitted]
[image: Normal Q-Q]
[image: Residuals vs Leverage]
[image: Scale-location]

Thanks so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a final model which fits your data very poorly, so you have to dig deeper in your data to find out why and also determine if it is possible to improve your model.

Perhaps you should start by looking at the distribution of the INCOME variable - in general, incomes tend to have a positively skewed distribution. If that is the case for your data, you should fit your model to the log-transformed INCOME.

Not sure how many predictor variables you start out with, but the next thing you should do before attempting to fit a model to the data would be to plot log(INCOME) against each of your predictor variables to get some sense of how each predictor is related to log(INCOME).

When starting your predictor selection process, you should focus on either AIC or BIC, depending on your modelling goals. If your model will be used for explanatatory purposes, then BIC makes more sense. If it will be used for predictive purposes, then AIC makes more sense. (Explanatory purposes would imply that you are interested in describing the association between each predictor and log(INCOME) after controlling for the effect of the other predictors in the model.)